# How to return an action value from a JavaScript callback in ANTLR?

Tags: javascript, antlr, antlr4

I am playing with the [ANTLR JavaScript target](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/JavaScript+Target). While I understand how to return a value directly in any target language I don't know how to handle the special JavaScript case where the returned value came from a callback.

For example, I know how to do this:

```
atom    returns [cell]
        : number { console.log('number: ' + $number.text); $cell = $number.text; }
        ;
```

But not this, in an asynchronous way **(it obviously doesn't work but it is for illustrating the concept. There can be a callback function passed to atom to send the result)**:

```
atom    returns [cell]
        : number {console.log('number: ' + $number.text); myfunc($number, function(a) {$cell = a;}); }
        ;
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to do that anyway.

Comment: Why not? Can you elaborate?

Comment: If there's a call to an asynchronous method with a callback, then nothing the callback does can possibly affect the return value of the surrounding function. The callback will run when the asynchronous operation completes, but by that time the original outer function will have returned.

Comment: Yes, that's the point of the question. Since ANTLR now supports JavaScript and JavaScript has a asynchronous nature, there must be a way to deal with this case. The second grammar section is obviously incorrect and only written to illustrate the concept.

Comment: OK; maybe I don't see precisely what you're trying to do. Are you wondering how you tell ANTLR that the generated parser needs to deal with asynchronous behavior introduced from the grammar rules? That's a really interesting question, but I regret to say that I can't help :(

Comment: Your second example isn't obviously asynchronous. Are you saying that **myfunc** is asynchronous and then calls the anonymous function on completion of the asynchronous activity (e.g., Ajax call)? Regardless, I don't see how this can work. The actions in the grammar are executed as the parsing occurs and each rule is recognized. You are specifying a return value from the rule that will, most likely, not be initialized yet when the parent context tries to use it. The parse will be synchronous - you cannot make it dependent on asynchronous operations.

Comment: @intheweeds do you say, and are you 100% sure, that antlr doesn't support async actions? The second example obviously doesn't work, it is just to illustrate something that happen all the time with JavaScript: you need to have async support to integrate it with your projects.

Comment: I guess it would really depend on what you were trying to do. Just to be sure, I played with an example that had syntax that is very similar to your second example. It **will** actually record a value in the **cell** member of the context object for the rule **after** the asynchronous call completes. What would **not** work is to have a rule that depended on the **atom** rule whose action depended on the **cell** value of that atom (because the value of **cell** would not be calculated until after the asynchronous action had completed).